# Can we create a remote event receiver to prevent users from deleting files but allow them to rename the files

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, document-library, permissions, remote-event-receiver

We created a custom permission level which mimic the built-in Contribute permission level but without the ability to delete items and versions, by unchecking those 2 checkboxes:-

[image: User's image]

Our intention was to prevent users from moving folders and deleting folders, but currently users cannot rename files also. So does anyone face this issue? and have any solution for it? not sure if remote event receivers might be an approach to invest in to solve this issue (prevent users from deleting files but allow them to rename the files)?